# Problem with kickstart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kickstart

I created a kickstart file ks.cfg and then I have put that in the bootable disk**(Ubuntu 10.04)** and then added the following line to the isolinux.cfg linux ks=ks.cfg and have not removed any other lines from the isoconfig.cfg file and then while installing the installation is not automated,again it is asking for language and all.

If i removed include menu.cfg or any other line from isolinux.cfg i am getting a boot error.

What should i do now to automate the installation.Where should i add the boot parameters so that installation will start from the ks.cfg .

Thanks and Regards
Ravi Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Where is your ks.cfg located ? You should define the "ks" parameter with a URL, like "ks=http://192.168.1.10/ks.cfg"

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion your installation does not see the ks.cfg file. Maybe you should specify the absolute path: ks=/cdrom/ks.cfg or so. From [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html) :ks=cdrom:/path/to/ks.cfg is the right syntax. Personally, I was disappointed with Ubuntu's kickstart implementation and went using preseed.

Comment: Hi,
I have given the absolute path,even then the installation is not automated..Its still happening in the normal way.

Comment: You need to use the Alternate ISO, not the regular one. This might be the problem. Can you make sure you use the correct ISO?